# Overwrite image located outside django MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: python, django

My models.imageField uploads images to a directory outside of the django directory path. In storages.py I have a function 'upload_to' that sets the directory and filename. It all works perfectly except that I cannot overwrite an existing file with the same name, django simply appends some random text to the file name.

**My question is:**

How can I overwrite the remote file?

**What I have tried:**

I have played around with the script suggested here:
https://www.itachay.com/2020/04/override-replace-uploaded-file-in-django.html

Which would work if I was using MEDIA_ROOT, but with my remote file I only ever get the django "SuspiciousFileOperation" warning.

Here is my 'working' code albeit that it won't overwrite any existing file of the same name.

```
models.py

from .storages import upload_to, remote_storage

class Newsletter(models.Model):
    image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, storage=remote_storage)
```

```
storages.py

from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    dir_name = 'volume-'+str(instance.pk)
    filename = 'image_1'+filename[-4:]
    return '%s/%s' % (dir_name, filename)


remote_storage = FileSystemStorage(
                    location='/Users/some_dir/Documents/dev/mediatest/',
                    base_url='/Users/some_dir/Documents/dev/mediatest/'
                                )
```

My Tries:

**TRY 1:**

```
settings.py

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_TRACK = '/Users/some_dir/Documents/dev/mediatest/'
```

```
models.py

from .storages import upload_to, OverwriteStorage

class Newsletter(models.Model):
    image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, storage=OverwriteStorage())
```

```
storages.py

FileSystemStorage(
    location='/Users/some_dir/Documents/dev/mediatest/',
    base_url='/Users/some_dir/Documents/dev/mediatest/'
                )

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_TRACK, name))
        return name
```

**Try 1 Condition:**

1. New record created and image is saved.
2. Record edited and a new image is selected and saved.

**Try 1 RESULT:**

1. Image is saved to the local django directory, not the remote media/volume-1 (no errors)
2. FileNotFoundError at /admin/newsletter/newsletter/6/change/
   [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/some_dir/Documents/dev/mediatest/volume-1/image_1.png'

**TRY 2:**

The only change to the above script is to OverwriteStorage()

```
class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        if self.exists(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_TRACK, name)):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_TRACK, name))
        return name
```

**Try 2 Condition:**

1. Same record edited and image is saved.

**Try 2 Result**

1. SuspiciousFileOperation at /admin/newsletter/newsletter/6/change/
   The joined path (/Users/some_dir/Documents/dev/mediatest/volume-1/image_1.png) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/some_dir/Documents/dev/backoffice/media)

Comment: Hi! Could you show your tries with the script suggested in https://www.itachay.com/2020/04/override-replace-uploaded-file-in-django.html? It seems the correct way to do it.

Comment: Many thanks iserrance, i've added the tries.

Comment: Hi! I repeated your code but I actually couldn't use an absolute path in upload_to. With relative path is working fine.